# Android-MobileProfiles: How to change Profile to silent or ringer automatically, on a change of mobile location?

Tags: android

I need to change my profile to silent, pager or ringing based on the location(the location is set as home or office based on geo information) so when ever phone is at that location it would change to that profile automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Smarter Profiles - Automatically switches your predefined profiles based on location and time for your Android phone

- http://intofan.com/smarterprofiles/
- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.intofan.android.smartprofiles